# Python/Flask - if x in y not returning true

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask api endpoint that return message JSON objects.  Each has a field called `recipients` which has a list of `id` integers.  The endpoint takes one query which is `id` it should then return each message that the queried `id` is in the `recipients` list.

```
@app.route('/api/uscorr/messages', methods=['GET'])
def getMessages():

    # Check that id was passed in the query
    if 'id' in request.args:
        id = request.args['id']
    else:
        return "id is a mandatory query field"

    # Initialize blank results list
    results = []

    # Iterate through all messages in the database
    for message in messages:
        print("Looking for {} in list {}".format(id, message['recipients']))
        # Check if the queried id is in the list of message recipients
        if id in message['recipients']:
            print("Nothing makes it here")
            # Append current message to the results array as it is intended for the queried id
            results.append(message)

    # Check the number of results, return message if there were zero results
    if len(results) < 1:
        return "No match for found for the specified employee number"
    else:
        # Return the results list
        return jsonify(results)
```

The collection `messages` is a list of JSON message objects.

```
messages = [
  {
    "id": "9925bc3a-f0d4-44c4-adb6-0e7d4077cda7",
    "recipients": [
      7654674,
      432156,
      123456
    ],
    "subject": "labore eiusmod anim",
    "message": "Deserunt non magna mollit duis eiusmod dolor enim adipisicing cillum sunt incididunt veniam nulla. Veniam eiusmod consectetur aliquip nisi officia nisi labore in aute proident aliqua eiusmod Lorem tempor. Minim id voluptate incididunt culpa veniam et excepteur tempor fugiat ad adipisicing occaecat.",
    "priority": "Urgent",
    "from": "Veronica Davenport"
  }, ...
```

The statement `if id in message['recipients']:` never resolves as `true` despite the printed out from about if indicating that it should.

[image]

I get the gut feeling I missed something very basic.

Comment: Are you sure the list isn't a list of strings? What you're trying is a valid python construct so that's the only potential reason I can think of

Comment: As an aisde, i is not recommended to use `id` as it's a built in keyword

Comment: The direct output is shown in the bottom picture, look like `int` to me

Comment: Please try to print `type(id), type(message['recipients'][0])`. I think the type of `id` is a string

Comment: @YangHG spot on.  I forgot to cast `id` to `int` so it was a string.

Comment: @YangHG throw up an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @taesu do you have some documentation you could link to on best practices?  I'm just starting to play with APIs and anything like that would be appreciated.

Comment: @iShaymus I think it's not a enforcing standards, just a suggestion. It's same to python built-in names, you could define it, but after this line you can't access built-in `id` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert `request.args['id']` to `int`. Normally it is a `string`.

```
id = int(request.args['id'])
```

But please check if it is a valid digit first.

```
request.args['id'].isdigit()
```

To simplify this conversion, you could also consider using `WTForms`. Docs here: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/

It often work with `Flask-WTF` together.

A simple example:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class TestForm(Form):
    money = IntegerField('ID', validators=[InputRequired()])
```